# How can I make it so if the first player inputs a wrong command then it will a specific prompt?

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans

I am trying to make a game of rock-paper-scissors-spock-lizard. I have been learning about if/else statements. I am trying to make it so that if player1 inputs an invalid command then it will print out "Sorry, this is not a valid command" like with the else statement. It works if both players input a command and one is wrong, but not if just player1 did. Could you help me figure out what I am supposed to do?
Here is my code:

```
    package csc212hw03;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String player1;
    String player2;
    String player1Choice;
    String player2Choice;
    String line;

           // “1” for Paper
    //“2” for Rock
    //“3” for Spock
    //“4” for Lizard
    //“5”for Scissors
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Player 1, please enter your name:");
   player1 = kb.nextLine();

   System.out.println("Player 2, please enter your name:");
   player2 = kb.nextLine();

   System.out.println(player1 + ", please enter your command:");
   player1Choice = kb.nextLine();

   System.out.println(player2 + ", please enter your command:");
   player2Choice = kb.nextLine();

   if (player1Choice.equals("1") && player2Choice.equals("2")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Paper covers Rock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player2Choice.equals("2") && player1Choice.equals("1")){
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Paper covers Rock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("1")&& player2Choice.equals("1")) {
       System.out.println("Draw!");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("2")&& player2Choice.equals("2")) {
       System.out.println("Draw!");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("1")&& player2Choice.equals("3")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Paper disproves Spock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("3") && player2Choice.equals("1")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Paper disproves Spock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("3")&& player2Choice.equals("3"))  {
       System.out.println("Draw!");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("2") && player2Choice.equals("3")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Spock vaporizes Rock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("3") && player2Choice.equals("2")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Spock vaporizes Rock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("3") && player2Choice.equals("5")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Spock smashes Scissors.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("5") && player2Choice.equals("3")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Spock smashes Scissors.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("5") && player2Choice.equals("5")) {
       System.out.println("Draw!");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("2") && player2Choice.equals("5")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Rock crushes Scissors.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("5") && player2Choice.equals("2")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Rock crushes Scissors.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("2") && player2Choice.equals("4")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Rock crushes Lizard.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("4") && player2Choice.equals("2")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Rock crushes Lizard.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("3") && player2Choice.equals("4")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Lizard poisons Spock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("4") && player2Choice.equals("3")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Lizard poisons Spock.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("5") && player2Choice.equals("1")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Scissors cuts Paper.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("1") && player2Choice.equals("5")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Scissors cuts Paper.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("5") && player2Choice.equals("4")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Scissors decpitates Lizard.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("4") && player2Choice.equals("5")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Scissors decapitates Lizard.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("5") && player2Choice.equals("5")) {
       System.out.println("Draw!");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("4") && player2Choice.equals("4")) {
       System.out.println("Draw!");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("4") && player2Choice.equals("1")) {
       System.out.println(player1 + " wins! Lizard eats Paper.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else if (player1Choice.equals("1") && player2Choice.equals("4")) {
       System.out.println(player2 + " wins! Lizard eats Paper.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");
   } else {
       System.out.println("I'm sorry, this is not a valid command.");
       System.out.println("Thank you for playing.");

   }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just asking for Player 1's choice once, put it in a while loop to ask until they input a valid response, like this

```
player1Choice = "";
boolean player1ChoiceValid = false;
while(!player1ChoiceValid){
    System.out.println(player1 + ", please enter your command:");
    player1Choice = kb.nextLine();
    if(player1Choice.equals("1")
            || player1Choice.equals("2")
            || player1Choice.equals("3")
            || player1Choice.equals("4")
            || player1Choice.equals("5")){
        player1ChoiceValid = true;
    }else{
        System.out.println("I'm sorry, this is not a valid command.");
    }
}
```

This will continuously loop the question until the input is valid, meaning it is 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5. This should also be done for Player 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
        while (true) {
            Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(player1 + ", please enter your command:");
            String player1Choice = kb.nextLine();

            if (!player1Choice.equals("1") || !player1Choice.equals("2") || !player1Choice.equals("3")
                    || !player1Choice.equals("4") || !player1.equals("5")) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, this is not a valid command");
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Also, you can think of more elegant approach in the if statement.